# How can I prove that if $A$ is a singular square matrix, then $\det A = 0$ without using Binet's Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Well, I need to prove that if $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix and it is singular, then $\det A = 0$, in order to show Binet's Theorem $\det(AB) = \det(A)\cdot\det(B)$ in the case when both $A$ and $B$ are singular square matrices.

I'll thank any help with this issue!

Comment: How do you define singular matrix then?

Comment: A non - invertible matrix?

Comment: How do you define singular, and how do you define determinant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $B=A \cdot C^T$ where $C$ is the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix) of $A$.

Then $b_{i,j}=\sum_k a_{i,k} \, c_{j,k}$, where $c_{j,k}$ is the $j,k$ [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of $A$.

If $i = j$ , that corresponds to the computation of the determinant of $A$ along the row $i$, hence $b_{i,i}=\det A$

If $i\ne j$ , that corresponds to the computation of the determinant of a matrix that's equal to $A$ except that the row $j$ has been overwriten by the contents of row $i$. But the determinant of a matrix with duplicated rows is zero, hence $b_{i,j}=0$.

This can be written $$A \cdot C^T = \det(A) \, I \tag{1}$$

If $\det A\ne 0$ then we can write $$ A \, \frac{C^T}{\det A}=I \iff A^{-1}=\frac{C^T}{\det A}=\frac{adj(A)}{\det A} \tag{2}$$

(This esentially amounts to rediscovering/proving [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix))

That is, $\det A\ne 0 \implies A^{-1} $ exists (hence, $A$ is non singular).

Consequently, if $A$ is singular (i.e. the inverse does not exist) then we must have $\det A=0$.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand... since the inverse is unique, if it exists, it must be $\frac{C^T}{|A|}$, but if it doesn't, the only way for it to be undefined is when $|A| = 0$, since $C^T$ is always defined, right?

Comment: More or less. I've proved that _if_ $|A|\ne 0 $ then the inverse exists, and $A$ is not singular. By [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) (or Reductio ad absurdum, if you prefer) it follows: if $A$ is singular then $|A|= 0 $.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, $\det$ is an alternating multilinear form in the matrix columns. By assumption, there exists non-zero $v$ with $Av=0$, i.e., the column vectors are linearly dependent. Use this and alternating multilinearity to show that $\det A$ equals $\det B$ for a matrix $B$ with one column equal to $0$, and there we see from linearity in that column that $\det B=0$.

Comment: "By definition" Well, that depends. There are many different definitions out there. "By assumption" Again, depending on your definition is, that's not directly the assumption. If you don't use the "right" definitions, then showing these things isn't difficult, but it must be done if one is to follow this answer. And if you do it that way, then much of the work lies in showing these things.

Comment: @Arthur Agreed. In the absence of a specific definition in the OP, I took the "the unique alternating $n$-form that maps $I\mapsto 1$" as definition of $\det$. Other definitions may lead to different answers with different methods. One will finally suit the asker best, possibly others may be helpful to future visitors. (Essentially, *Wuestenfix*'s Gauß elimination is the down-to-earth formulation of the alternating-form argument - and I assume his way is preferable)

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic operations you can do with matrices and their determinants: First, if any pair of columns (or rows) of a matrix is interchanged, the determinant is multiplied with −1. Second, if a scalar multiple of one column is added to another column, the value of the determinant is not altered. In this way, you can do Gauss elimination on the matrix and keep track of the determinant of the matrix. If the matrix is singular, you end up with a zero column (or row) giving you determinant 0.

Comment: Would this be the same if I try to get the answers to $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$? If $A$ was invertible, I'd only get $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, but it it's not, then I'd have infinitely many answer for $\vec{x}$ and that would mean that I have free variables and I'd have less equations than variables, right?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse exists when the determinant is nonzero.  There is a formula for it:  $$A^{-1}=\frac1{\operatorname{det}A}\operatorname{adj}A$$, where $\operatorname{adj}A$ is the transpose of the matrix of cofactors,  the so-called *adjugate* of $A$.

Comment: Since it is unique, it must be the way you wrote it, right? Then if $A$ is singular, then that $A^-1$ is undefined and the only way this is the case is if $det A = 0$ from that formula, right?

Comment: Right.   This actually gives the _contrapositive_  of the statement you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two proof

1. Permutation change the sign of the determinant
2. Multiplying a row by a constant multiply the determinant by this constant

Then, you can just say if you have a singular matrix S, 2 row $r_i$ and $r_j$ are linearly dependent. You can multiply $r_i$ by a constant C to get a new matrix S' where $r_i$ = $r_j$.

We know
\begin{equation} 
det(S') = C det(S)
\end{equation}
Then, you can swap $r_i$ and $r_j$ but you have the same matrix has before so
\begin{equation}
det(S') = -det(S') = -C det(S) = C det(S)
\end{equation}
The equation det(S) = -det(S) means det(S) is 0.